# Smartsheet API create/update reports possible?

Tags: smartsheet-api

Just verifying that Reports can not be created or modified using the API.

I'm using Python.

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The Smartsheet API allows you to [publish](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#publish-report) or [share](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#share-report) an existing report, but it does not allow you to create or modify.

We would love to hear about your specific use case as we consider future enhancements to the API. Let us know what you're trying to do at api@smartsheet.com.

Comment: I just spent a nearly an hour updating a set of reports for the customer. I was doing two things: 1) add a column to display and 2) modify the What? criteria to add second criteria. This takes so long because of the number of reports and the time delay between opening the report, opening the report builder, running the report, and closing it.

Comment: The recent change to Smartsheet (2018-10-03) for MULTI_CONTACT_LIST would be a VERY useful use case for Report modifications.